# How to unbind event from asp.net control?

Tags: asp.net, events

I have the following dropdownlist control.

```
<asp:dropdownlist ID="ddlFeeds" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFeeds_OnSelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:dropdownlist>
```

How do i unbind ddlFeeds_OnSelectedIndexChanged from ddlFeeds?

Comment: Do you want to do this from the codebehind?  From Javascript on the page?  Globally?

Answer (score 2):

After the page has initialized, set the ddlFeeds.SelectedIndexChanged += null. You will need to do this on every load, irregardless of postback.

A better plan would be to just eliminate the OnSelectedIndexChanged attribute from the ASPX template.

Comment: I did ddlFeeds.SelectedIndexChanged = null; and I get a compilation error with the msg: 'CS0079: The event 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.SelectedIndexChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -='

Comment: you have to do ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += null;

Answer (score 0):

ddlFeeds.SelectedIndexChanged -= ddlFeeds_OnSelectedIndexChanged;